# What is the prototype Spring Bean used for?

Tags: spring, thread-safety, singleton, prototype

By default, the Bean created by Spring is singleton. They are thread-safe because they are stateless. When we want Spring to create a stateful Bean, we need to use prototype scope for the Bean definition. We need to take care of the thread-safe issues for them. All stateless Bean will be polluted when they are injected by the prototype bean. So, I just can not image where we can use the prototype scope. Can you give some typical scenario that we can / need to use prototype Spring Bean? Also how can we void the stateful pollution on other singleton beans?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many reasons to use prototype scope, e.g., any time you'd use "new" instead of using a singleton. A per-user bean, a per-request bean, a collection of unique beans, etc. After all, in any non-trivial application, don't you use non-singletons far more than singletons?

Singleton-scoped beans aren't thread-safe simply because they're singletons–they must be *written* to be thread-safe. They don't become thread-safe magically. A bean's scope is just that, its scope: it doesn't make the bean *appropriate* for the particular scope–that's up to the developer.

Comment: I have to disagree with my good friend Dave here. Personally, I have had 0 good reasons to create a prototype Spring Bean in any of my production applications. I would ask yourself why do you need this object as a bean. If it is truly a stateful object, is it an Entity bean which it created by JPA or JDBC such that you aren't calling new anyway? Is it a View DTO like object, again just call new there.

Here is a link to Marten saying the same thing.. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/81737-when-to-set-scope-as-prototype

Comment: why not use @Scope("session")

Comment: @SAM If that suits your needs, no reason not to. But in the context of a web app a session-scoped bean is very different than a prototype bean, and may not be what you actually need. Different scopes serve different purposes. So, lacking any context to your question, "because I need a prototype bean"?

Comment: @Dave: If i declare DAO's scope as session will spring create multiple SQL connections for executing the queries, or will it use the same conneciton for every DAO operation.

Comment: @SAM I have no idea. "Session" means different things in different contexts, e.g., in a web app a session is tied to a client connection, and DB connections will not be shared across users. If you have a question, ask it, don't try to have a full conversation within a completely different question.

Answer (score 1):

I perceive prototype scoped beans as an alternative to factory classes used to create objects. The difference is in case of prototype beans spring will save you some code for dependency injection and will also automatically proxy your objects for transactions etc. when appropriate.

I myself prefer the factory approach. One reasonable scenario for prototype scope I encountered was a stateful object, needed by different known beans and each required its own copy. A dedicated factory class would be redundant in this scenario since I did not need to create objects on the fly but only during other beans' instantiation.